# Does anyone know how to integrate PayPal account with the Webflow shopping cart?

Tags: paypal, webflow

I am trying to integrate my Webflow shopping cart with my PayPal business account.
It looks like I have everything set up correctly in Webflow but when I enable checkout, republish and try out the site, I get a 'shopping cart not enabled message'.

[My site](http://nittygrittyinc.webflow.io/)

[My site's Read-Only Link](https://preview.webflow.com/preview/nittygrittyinc?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=dashboard&utm_content=nittygrittyinc&preview=081466d71d226bc3787162e72564693e&workflow=preview)

Comment: This does not look like a programming question. It looks like a question for [Webflow Support](https://university.webflow.com/contact).

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with the connection, check the payment method in Webflow.
If the PayPal icon is lit, then the API/SDK connection between PayPal and Webflow has been established.
Webflow provides the interface between their API and the hosted site.
Therefore, if the PayPal payment icon is lit, and you have a green 'Setup is complete!' in the eCommerce setup guide menu, then the problem is with the PayPal account.
In my case, my client's new account had been verified but not authorized yet.